# Why state is not declared when it was set properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get data from server and set that data in state. Why state is not saved??

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const claimNumber = 'T1339838' 
    const { runtime } = this.context
    const data = await runtime.select('comments-get', { claimNumber : claimNumber})

    // THIS commentsData ARE empty
    this.setState = ({ commentsData: data, })

    console.log("COMENTS DATA: ", this.state.commentsData)
  }
```

Comment: Typo: You put an `=` between the function name and the brackets surrounding its arguments, so you overwrote the function instead of calling it. It's async too, so you would need to use a callback to read the updated data. `this.setState({ commentsData: data, }, () => console.log("COMENTS DATA: ", this.state.commentsData));`

Comment: Missing semicolons?

Comment: @Frost — No, that's fine with ASI rules.

Comment: @Quentin yeas thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting state incorrectly. Also, setState is async so you might want to put that console log statement in setState callback.

```
this.setState({ commentsData: data }, () => {
    console.log("COMENTS DATA: ", this.state.commentsData)
})
```